# Как правильно написать метод для работы с Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Учусь. Написал такое. Но оно не работает, в консоле выдает ошибку

`Имя "driver" не существует в текущем контексте.`

Какие правки сделать чтобы оно заработало?

```cs
void myTest()
{

    IWebElement inputEmail = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#email"));
    inputEmail.SendKeys("Мой емейл");

}

private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-notifications"); // Отключаем notifications
    //chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");  //Запуск в фоне

    ChromeDriverService chromeservice = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    chromeservice.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;  //спрятать консоль 

    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeservice, chromeOptions);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.mysite.com/");


    myTest();
}
```

Comment: Рано вы взяли такой огроменный и сложный инструмент, как селениум, вам основы бы подучить. Вы драйвер где создаете? В обработчике `startButton_Click`, это у вас локальная переменная, которая живет только в этом методе. Ну а вызываете вы ее где? В `myTest`, совсем другом методе, который ничего не знает про локальные переменные других методов. Передавайте либо аргументом (`myTest(IWebDriver driver){...}`  ... `myTest(driver)`), либо вынесите переменную за пределы метода (`IWebDriver driver; private void startButton_Click(...){driver = new ChromeDriver(...);}`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Спасибо за разъяснение, вынес переменную за пределы метода и все заработало.